# What is the use of opener argument in built-in open() function?

Tags: python

I am playing with open function in python 3.5. I don't understand the usages of opener argument (Last argument) in open function. According to python documentation: A custom opener can be used by passing a callable as opener.

```
open(file, mode='r', buffering=-1, encoding=None, errors=None, newline=None, closefd=True, opener=None)
```

Can someone explain me why I need opener argument with help of an example.

Answer (score 2):

See the documentation [here](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#open).  The example they give is as follows:

```
import os
dir_fd = os.open('somedir', os.O_RDONLY)
def opener(path, flags):
    return os.open(path, flags, dir_fd=dir_fd)

with open('spamspam.txt', 'w', opener=opener) as f:
    print('This will be written to somedir/spamspam.txt', file=f)

os.close(dir_fd)  # don't leak a file descriptor
```

What this particular example does is create an opener that will always take paths and interpret them as relative to a given directory of your choosing (`somedir`).  You could imagine using more complicated logic to look in specific directories depending on file type, or separating a large number of files into a directory structure based on the first couple characters of the filename and writing a specific function as your opener that will locate them.  All of this would encapsulate the file-locating logic into a single function as your opener.

Comment: So I can call any function from Os module (or from other modules) to change the properties of my file?

Comment: Your opener function can do anything it wants, but it has to return a file descriptor, which means you have to open a file and obtain its file descriptor.  `os.open` accomplishes this, and returns the file descriptor for the file it opened so that `opener` can return that file descriptor.  Whatever you do, you're probably going to want to open your file with `os.open`, but you can use your `opener` to implement some logic for determining which file to open or what arguments to pass to `os.open`.

Answer (score 0):

opener can be used to create files with other than the default ownership
and permissions:

```
def _dminopener(path: str, flags: int) -> int:
    """opener for open() rw-rw---- and adm (4) group"""
    f = os.open(path, flags, mode=0o660)
    os.chown(-1,4)
    return f
```

Answer (score -1):

Honestly, I have never used the *opener* parameter in real Python code...

A possible usage would be to use a special *file system* that would require special API. For example, you could store *sequential files* in a database by keeping the whole file in memory and reading and writing it in a single operation.

There used to be *indexed files*, that is files that contained sequential streams, each stream having a name. In that case, you could access that transparently with a custom opener.

The last example I can imagine, would the the [streams](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/en-en/library/windows/desktop/aa364404%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) in Windows NTFS file system. Each file has a default stream, but can have as many alternate streams that you want. A special opener could be used to access transparently alternate streams on a file, or to store special meta-data in on specific alternate stream at open or close time...